# Create and sign in Asp.net Identity User in Mvc Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-identity, actionfilterattribute

recently i faceed the need to create a user for every guest user , so i thought the best option to do so is mvc action filter, but since we cant use async method in action filters. i changed the use of every async methods to not async methods .

i need to create user and then sign in him/her. i found not async methods for creating user but for signing in him/her i did not find any method. 
so what shoud i do ? 
is there another for achieving this ?

here my code so far:

```
if (!context.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var guestUser = new User();
            guestUser.UserName = $"{guestUser.Id}@fake.com";
            guestUser.Email = $"{guestUser.Id}@fake.com";
            var createUserResult = _userManager.Create(guestUser, "fakeUserIsNoImportant");
            if (createUserResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var result = _signInManager.SignInPasswordAsync("Email", "Pasword","Rememberme", "shouldLockout");
            }
        }
```

i just want to know instead of SignInPasswordAsync , what can i use ?

Comment: there is not any method with name of SignInPassword , in another word there is not any implemention for Sign in without async. and mvc 5 does not have support for calling async method in action filters.

Comment: There is an extension method SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false) in Asp.net Identity 2.1

Comment: Perhaps the filter is not the right place for this. Your filter should redirect un-authenticated users to an action where they get an Auth-cookie (get signed-on).

Answer (score 0):

You really need `SignInPasswordAsync`

you can edit your method signature in order to let `..Async` method work confortably... Add `public async Task<ActionResult>` at the beginning of your method definition.